# Microservices and messaging pattern

Tags: microservices, message, messagebroker

With a solution based on microservices, as it is usually described in "literature", in front of the services there is a lightweight layer used, for example, as a load balancer or to implement some kind of authentication and/or authorization.

I am wondering how, in this type of solution, microservices can communicate using messages. If there isn't a message broker, is messaging implemented directly at the level of JMS (or similar)?

Is it really possible to implement a proper messaging solution without using any message broker?

Comment: I can recommend reading this: http://www.benstopford.com/2018/04/27/book-designing-event-driven-systems/

Answer (score 1):

Messages or events are use for async communication and microservices in this case are just a small piece of code that react to new messages in certain way. You can have a mechanism in place to send messages from service to another but that will just not be efficient or clean. So we do need a message broker in place whose responsibility is to manage events/messages.
You cannot in my opinion, live without a message broker

Answer (score 1):

Your single question has different separate questions inside it.

**(1) Can a micro-services system survive without aid of a message broker system?**

Yes, it definitely can.

**(2) Can a micro-services system with an authentication/authorization (identity server) layer still survive without aid of a message broker system?**

Yes, Still it can.

**(3) Then, why on earth people use message brokers to communicate among micro-services?**

Message brokers (Message Queues) is a proven ***clean*** way to implement communication (enterprise integration) among sub services.

What does it mean by ***clean***?

- Asynchronous Communication (No waiting)
- Can easily scale out different services (No JVM dependencies, can deploy different services in different servers)
- Can manage events centrally (just another pub sub)
- Scalability (Easy to add another service which needs to communicate with some existing services)

**(4) Now, what are the other alternatives without using message queues?**

- Simple re-direction (good alternative, if you hardly try to scale your system further)
- [Service Provider Interfacing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) (SPI) (Again good for small scale, but you are trapped with same JVM sharing limitation)